# How to combine label and combo box as one custom control in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

My requirement is to combine `sap.m.Label` and `sap.m.ComboBox` as one single control without losing functionality of standard controls.

I have created one dropdown custom control. Inside that I've added two aggregations - Label & ComboBox. And I am able to set properties and also both controls are getting rendered in UI. But I am not able to set aggregation 'items' of ComboxBox having ListItems which should be displayed on clicking down arrow of ComboBox. I am not sure where and what code I have to write for items aggregation. (Also note that my requirement is that I can bind the items also from JSON model).

```js
// This is Dropdown.js file - code for custom control    
sap.ui.define("com/CustomControls/controls/Dropdown", [
  "sap/ui/core/Control",
  "sap/m/Label",
  "sap/m/ComboBox"
], function (Control, Label, ComboBox) {
  "use strict";

  var Dropdown = Control.extend("com.CustomControls.controls.Dropdown", {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        text: {
          type: "string",
          defaultValue: "Decimal"
        },
        required: {
          type: "boolean",
          defaultValue: false
        }
      },
      aggregations: {
        _label: {
          type: "sap.m.Label",
          multiple: false,
          visibility: "hidden"
        },
        _combobox: {
          type: "sap.m.ComboBox",
          multiple: false,
          visibility: "hidden"
        },
        items: { // I am not sure where to write item aggregation and how to render it
          type: "sap.ui.core.Item",
          multiple: "true",
          singularName: "items"
        }
      },
      defaultAggregation: "items",
      events: {}
    },

    init: function () {
      this.setAggregation("_label", new Label({
        width: "30%"
      }).addStyleClass("sapUiSmallMarginTop"));
      this.setAggregation("_combobox", new ComboBox({
        width: "70%",
      }));
    },

    renderer: function (oRM, oControl) {
      oRM.write("<div");
      oRM.writeControlData(oControl);
      oRM.addClass("dropdownClass");
      oRM.writeClasses();
      oRM.writeStyles();
      oRM.write(">");
      oControl.getAggregation("_label").setText(oControl.getText());
      oControl.getAggregation("_label").setRequired(oControl.getRequired());
      oRM.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_label"));
      oRM.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_combobox"));
      oRM.write("</div>");
    }
  });

  return Dropdown;
});
```

Comment: Which UI5 version are you using?

Comment: version - 1.82, I'm doing development in sap webide.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect use case for [`sap.ui.core.XMLComposite`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.XMLComposite). <del>Give it a try!</del> → **Update:** it's [deprecated](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/25ae0f1a4e8d9da209ff7241e05f87c60b58b885#diff-a867a3a126ec890883d1861ae2a3994c38e496ce82c596c29b558b7ef3c808d2) now. :(

Below are snippets from [https://embed.plnkr.co/hX27FEX6tD818iWi/](https://embed.plnkr.co/hX27FEX6tD818iWi/?show=view%2FApp.view.xml,preview).
[image]

### Control definition (sample)

File 1: `demo/control/MyLabelComboBox.control.xml`

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m">
  <HBox id="containerBox"
    alignItems="Baseline"
    width="{$this>width}"
    renderType="Bare"
    wrap="Wrap">
    <Label id="innerLabel"
      required="{$this>required}"
      text="{$this>text}:"
      labelFor="innerComboBox"
      wrapping="true"
      wrappingType="Hyphenated"
      class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd">
      <layoutData>
        <FlexItemData alignSelf="Center" />
      </layoutData>
    </Label>
    <ComboBox id="innerComboBox" placeholder="{$this>placeholder}">
      <layoutData>
        <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
      </layoutData>
    </ComboBox>
  </HBox>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

File 2: `demo/control/MyLabelComboBox.js`

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/XMLComposite",
], function(XMLComposite) {
  "use strict";

  return XMLComposite.extend("demo.control.LabelComboBox", {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        "text": {
          type: "string",
          bindable: true,
        },
        "required": {
          type: "boolean",
          bindable: true,
        },
        "placeholder": {
          type: "string",
          bindable: true,
        },
        "width": {
          type: "sap.ui.core.CSSSize",
          bindable: true,
          defaultValue: "100%",
        },
      },
      aggregations: {
        "items": {
          type: "sap.ui.core.Item",
          multiple: true,
          bindable: true,
          forwarding: {
            idSuffix: "--innerComboBox",
            aggregation: "items",
            forwardBinding: true,
          }
        }
      },
      defaultAggregation: "items",
    },
  });
});
```

Since `XMLComposite` already takes care of rendering internal controls, **no custom renderer is required**!

- [Documentation: XML Composite Controls](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/b83a4dcb7d0e46969027345b8d32fd44)
- [Other samples of XML Composite Controls](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.ui.core.XMLComposite)

---

#### Note

- Despite defining the control with `<core:FragmentDefinition>` / unlike Fragments, an XMLComposite control does have its own HTML representation in DOM ([related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2423)), which wraps the "real" controls inside. It is **not** the `<HBox>` in the above case!
- Depending on the use case, you might want to implement some of the interfaces:

  - `sap.uxap.IHeaderContent` if the control should be displayed in the header of `sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout`.
  - `sap.m.IOverflowToolbarContent` if the control should be able move to the overflow area in `sap.m.OverflowToolbar`.
  - ... *(See API reference for more interfaces)*